# Safari v15 not working on Mac Pro 5,1 with Catalina

Tags: mac, safari, catalina

Today i installed the new update released on 20th Sept for Safari,

Build 15612.1.29.41.4

It has stopped working, i have tried a new user account, same issue,

Anyone else encountered this ?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here on MacBook Pro with Catalina. Apple Support said that they were not aware of any issues and recommended a reinstall of macOS, but that did not fix the issue as Safari is still at version 15.0. I am now considering deleting the Safari app before reinstalling again, but am not sure whether that will fix or worsen the problem.

Comment: when they said reinstall, did they not mean a clean install :) anyway, ill sit and wait for a fix, im hapilly using firefox for the moment. seems like a long wait ahead until apple sort themselves out. there is no way im going to reinstall an os for a web browser, its just daft that they even think people do that.

Comment: Actually, they did explicitly suggest a clean install, but I am not willing to try that (yet). So I first tried Option-Cmd-R while rebooting but that did not downgrade Safari. Then I downloaded the latest version of Catalina from the Mac App Store which is 12 months old and, according to Apple Support, should still contain an older version of Safari. Running that did result in an additional app compatibility error, but kept Safari at v15.0.

Comment: yeah, i think id hold off, your going to break your system, and apple wont care mate. the binary looks nackered. and if you install catalina it will keep existing version as its the newest. no way to proceed yet, apple are just wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

The link in this thread appears to fix the problem: https://reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/ps7iq0/safari_not_working_after_catalina_2021005_safari

I used https instead of http:

https://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/15/01/002-02859-A_TFTOEP7KTW/c962h7kwercno4bxxaql4o2g03y80pefij/Safari15.0CatalinaAuto.pkg